# pip- Redis with Django channels

Tags: django, sockets, channel, django-channels

Error connecting to localhost:6379. No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

```
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
  "default": {
    "BACKEND": "asgi_redis.RedisChannelLayer",
    "CONFIG": {
        "hosts": [("localhost", 6379)],
    },
    "ROUTING": "mysite.routing.channel_routing",
},
```

}

pip install asgi_redis complete, I am following http://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting-started.html#running-with-channels

Comment: anyone... ? still failing at this .

Comment: Have you actually installed Redis? Is it running?

Answer (score 2):

```
# Channel layer definitions
# http://channels.readthedocs.org/en/latest/deploying.html#setting-up-a-channel-backend
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "asgi_redis.RedisChannelLayer",
        "CONFIG": {
            "hosts": [os.environ.get('REDIS_URL', 'redis://localhost:6379')],
        },
        "ROUTING": "mysite.routing.channel_routing",
    },
}
```

My .env has redis url set to : `redis://localhost:6379`

Make sure that you have a redis instance installed in your machine. 
Try checking it with `redis-cli ping`. If you recieve a pong message back then the redis instance is running.

```
asgi-redis==0.13.1
redis==2.10.5
```

Make sure that your virtual env has these two installed.
If you are using heroku please check to see if you have provisioned the redis instance.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem, following the same tutorial. I fixed it by installing Redis seperatly and running the redis-server process in the background so channels could connect to it. I'm on Windows so i downloaded this [version](https://github.com/rgl/redis/downloads).

Comment: I've tried installing that - when I opened the Redis client first line that appears says it also can't connect to Redis at 127:0:0:1:6379: uknown error @Bram

Comment: You should navigate to the folder where you installed Redis, there you will find a executable called redis-server, this is what you should run. The redis client is just a client that will try to connet to the redis-server, but since it's not running you can't connect. You don't  need the client, in this case Django will basically be the client.